# Uber API Map updates when 'in-progress' state

Tags: uber-api

Working with Uber API and trying to understand if GET /requests/{request_id}/map provides real time updates on the map for the ride in “in-progress” state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The map is [available after the trip goes into "accepted" state](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-map-get#ride-request-map), not before. You will see a map with the route, ETA, and other ride details. Here's how the [sandbox map response](https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/map) looks like:

[image]

> In production, this link will serve a full-page responsive map and trip information.